# I am getting errors in this script and nothing is visible on tkinter display

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menubar

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
class menu_w:
    
    def nothing(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.menubar= Menu(root)
        root.config(menu=self.menubar)
        self.filemenu= Menu(root,tearoff=0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="New",command=self.nothing)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="open",command=self.nothing)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="save",command=self.nothing)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="save as",command=self.nothing)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label=File,menu=self.filemenu)
   
k=menu_w(root)   
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What error are you getting? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Should `self.filemenu=Menu(root,tearoff=0)` be `self.filemenu=Menu(self.menubar,tearoff=0)` instead.  Also `self.menubar.add_cascade(label=File,...)` should be `self.menubar.add_cascade(label='File',...)`.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include the full error, and describe what you've done to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define two objects in `self.menubar.add_cascade`, notably `File` and the method `filemenu`, below script will work.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Menu

class menu_w:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.menubar = Menu(root)
        root.config(menu=self.menubar)

        self.filemenu = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=self.nothing)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="open", command=self.nothing)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="save", command=self.nothing)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="save as", command=self.nothing)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)

    def nothing(self):
        pass

    def filemenu(self):
        pass


def main():
    root = Tk()
    k = menu_w(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Some suggestions:

- do not use wildcard import, instead `from tkinter import *` do `from tkinter import Tk, Menu`
- Use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` construct
- bring `root = Tk()` to the `main` function